# URL Regex strange behaviour

Tags: php, regex, url

I have a regex used for identifying URLS with PHP, which works well:

```
~(?i)\b(?!.*?\<<)(?!.*?\.onion)((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|ftp://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))~
```

Except this breaks it, casuing catastrophic backtracking:

```
http://google.com(JavaScript_Add-on)
```

What's interesting is that this can be avoided by removing the parentheses, underscore or hyphen:

```
http://google.comJavaScript_Add-on //This is a match

http://google.com(JavaScriptAdd-on) //This is a match

http://google.com(JavaScript_Addon) //This is a match
```

Or removing the final letter 'n':

```
http://google.com(JavaScript_Add-o) //This is a match
```

Or removing the word 'Add':

```
http://google.com(JavaScript_-on) //This is a match
```

Does anyone know what's going on here and how this might be fixed?

Comment: Parentheses and underscores are not valid domain name characters: so none of those are valid URLs.

Comment: Please have a look at your modified regex at https://regex101.com/r/cI5eT2/2. Just adding `?` with `(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+?` can save lots of computing resources. I also added a `?` in the next non-capturing group. Answer: use *lazy* matching.

Answer (score 0):

Use lazy matching.

Just adding `?` with `(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+?` can save lots of computing resources. I also added a ? in the next non-capturing group. Here is an updated version:

```
(?i)\b(?!.*?\<<)
(?!.*?\.onion)
((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|ftp:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)
 (?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+?
 (?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*?\)
 |
 [^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’])
)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cI5eT2/3).

Comment: Thank you, that did fix the problem of the catastrophic backtracking. Unfortunately it also broke a few other URLS in my testing list:  https://regex101.com/r/cI5eT2/4

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine: 
*/(http[s]?://|www.)\w[^\s|<\^|(]+/gim;*